# Exon-exon junctions: compare experimental transcripts to reference annotation

Tags: rna-seq, software-recommendation, rna-splicing

My aim is to parse an experimental transcript set (obtained by RNAseq) to check which splice junctions are already reported in a reference annotation and which ones are new.

I tried `Regtools`:

1. feed the experimental alignment file (BAM: aligned transcripts to reference genome) to [Regtools junctions extract](https://regtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/commands/junctions-extract/)
2. use [Regtools junctions annotate](https://regtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/commands/junctions-annotate/) to compare with the reference annotation (GTF)

Exact commands I used for this are:

1. `[..]/regtools/build/regtools junctions extract aln_sorted.bam -o regtools.bed` - where the sorted BAM file has index in the same folder
2. `[..]/regtools/build/regtools junctions annotate regtools.bed [..]/ref/genome.fa [..]/ref/annotation.gtf -o regtools_annotate_out`

The alignments have been generated with [Minimap2](https://github.com/lh3/minimap2).

It did not behave as expected: this gives me as output a file with only junctions annotated as 'new' (`$11==N`), while other annotations should be possible according to the [manual](https://regtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/commands/junctions-annotate/):

> DA - This exon-exon junction is present in the transcriptome provided by the user(GTF) The ends of this junction are hence known donor and known acceptor sites according to the GTF file.
>
> NDA - This exon-exon junction is not present(novel) in the transcriptome provided by the user(GTF) The ends of this junction are
>    known donor and known acceptor sites according to the GTF file.
>
> D - This exon-exon junction is not present(novel) in the transcriptome provided by the user(GTF) The donor of this junction is a known donor but the acceptor is novel.
>
> A - This exon-exon junction is not present(novel) in the transcriptome provided by the user(GTF) The acceptor of this junction is a known acceptor but the donor is novel.
>
> N - This exon-exon junction is not present(novel) in the transcriptome provided by the user(GTF) The ends of this junction are hence not known donor/acceptor sites according to the GTF file.

My questions are:

- am I doing something wrong?
- do you have any experience with `Regtools` and can help debugging this behavior?
- do you have other suggestion to achieve the output I am seeking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [the script](https://github.com/lh3/minimap2/blob/master/misc/paftools.js) that comes with minimap2:

```sh
# install the k8 javascript shell
curl -L https://github.com/attractivechaos/k8/releases/download/v0.2.4/k8-0.2.4.tar.bz2 | tar -jxf -
cp k8-0.2.4/k8-`uname -s` $HOME/bin/k8    # assuming $HOME/bin in your $PATH

# acquire the latest minimap2
git clone https://github.com/lh3/minimap2.git

# print novel/erroneous junctions
minimap2/misc/paftools.js junceval -e anno.gtf rna-seq.sam > output.txt
```

Some example output:

```
P       read1    4       chr2    227332588       227340301       [(227332588,227340291)]
P       read2    1       chr9    19376379        19376489        [(19376388,19376493)]
P       read2    3       chr9    19378506        19378707        [(19378514,19378707)]
N       read3    1       chr1    160647335       160647472
N       read3    2       chr1    160647581       160659672
```

Here column 4–6 gives junctions not in the annotation. Column 7, if not empty, gives the list of annotated junctions/introns that overlap the junction in read alignment. Note that a big fraction of outputted records are errors in read alignment.

Comment: Hi @user172818, I have two questions on this: (1) could you please explain what the value in `$3` represent exactly - and (2) I had cases where the value in `$7` is a list of more than one tuple: do you have an explanation ?

Comment: @aechchiki 1) the exon number of the read. 2) an intron on a read may overlap multiple distinct introns in annotations due to alt splicing. The list gives all.

Answer (score 1):

For future googlers, Ding et al., 2017 published a [review](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5476949/): "Comparison of Alternative Splicing Junction Detection Tools Using RNA-Seq Data".

[Table 1](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5476949/table/T1/) has the list of software in this review.